# Convert date time value to expected with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, dataformat

I have an issue with converting a date time value to expected one with SimpleDateFormat (java), my expected format is `MM/yyyy`, and I want to convert 2 values to only 1 format

1. MM-yyyy for example 05-2012
2. yyyy-MM for example 2012-05

ouput is 05/2012.

I implemented something look like following

```
String expiry = "2012-01";
try {
    result = convertDateFormat(expiry, "MM-yyyy", expectedFormat);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    try {
        result = convertDateFormat(expiry, "yyyy-MM", expectedFormat);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private String convertDateFormat(String date, String oPattern, String ePattern) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat normalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(oPattern);
    Date d = normalFormat.parse(date);
    SimpleDateFormat cardFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(ePattern);
    return cardFormat.format(d);
}
```

Now, the return value is `6808`, I don't know why.

Kindly anyone help me on this case.

Comment: If you parse 2012-05, does it really try the second way? Or does it parse from the first format and get wrong result? You can make a condition on the "-" position before choosing format method.

Comment: please accept answers, you did not accept any answer till now.

Comment: I agree with @Quoi you do not accept any answers at all.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: If I change 2012-01 to 2012-05, the output is `7208` instead of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`SimpleDateFormat#setLenient()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to your `convertDateFormat` method:

```
private String convertDateFormat(String date, String oPattern, String ePattern) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat normalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(oPattern);
    normalFormat.setLenient(false); /* <-- Add this line -- */
    Date d = normalFormat.parse(date);
    SimpleDateFormat cardFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(ePattern);
    return cardFormat.format(d);
}
```

It will make the `convertDateFormat` fail if the date is incorrect.

This is explained in detail here: http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/